# Manually compare the main classes of a feature branch and take only those changes or should I merge the main development branch into this feature

Tags: git, merge

I have a git branch called `ASM_feature`, each task related to ASM should be a new branch and then merged back into the `ASM_feature` branch. Now the problem is the ASM branch has not been updated for a while. All the new branches are made from `development` which at the end of each spring the branch which is update to have all the features developed.

My question is should I manually compare the main classes of `ASM_feature` and take only those changes or should I merge `development` into `ASM_feature` as it has all the tasks of ASM and much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing is actually *not* the right way to do it to *merge*. One simple common example: You might pretty easily be taking a look at a section of code that was *deleted* on one of the branches. You check the difference.... and you see that a branch has the code, the other doesn't. How can you (without knowing what the common ancestor looks like) know if the code was deleted... or added? Unless you have a memory that works better than git, it could very easily lead you to keep the section of code *assuming* it's added code..... when it's not, it's the opposite. **merging** is the way to go (or rebase, if you want to get fancy in this particular case where your feature branch has merges).